# What does 'rare device' refer to?

Tags: meaning, literature

What does *rare device* refer to in the line 'It was a miracle of rare device' of Samuel Taylor Coleridge's poem, Kubla Khan?

Comment: +1 for caring enough about this poem to ask . . . 60 years ago my father wrote one of the standard interpretations!

Comment: In fact, a friend of mine brought this poem to my attention, for which I am very grateful. By the way, we especially like David Olney's dramatic delivery.

Comment: Lucky you. I first heard it from Frankie Goes to Hollywood's *Relax*. Ick.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The full lines are:

> The shadow of the dome of pleasure
>   Floated midway on the waves;
>   Where was heard the mingled measure
>   From the fountain and the caves.
>   It was a miracle of rare device,
>   A sunny pleasure-dome with caves of ice!

The phrase *rare device* means that it (in this case, the "pleasure-dome") was uniquely devised. In other words, it is an incredible, "miraculous" creation.

Another example in literature includes:

> "So fashioned a Porch with rare device..."
>   "As either might for wealth haue gotten beene, Or could be fram'd by workman's rare device."
>
> -Edmund Spenser, *The Faerie Queene*

Comment: Congratulations, but I'm unsure that the 'rare' usage is correct here! I presume that the writer misuses 'rare' for 'scarce'!

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández Coleridge, misuse? Never!

Comment: @JAM Since you are so expert on this matter, what could or should be the role of "poethics" in that context?

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández There are more things in heaven and English, O thou son of Fernando, than are dreamt of in thy philosophy.  Translation: It is ***summarily unlikely*** that Samuel Taylor Coleridge has misused English.  First cast out the beam out of thine own eye, and then shalt thou see clearly to cast out the mote out of thy brother’s.

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández: "Misuses" is a pretty strong word. Coleridge was a poet. He wrote poetry a couple hundred years ago. His poetry has been celebrated and taught in schools ever since. I'll leave you with a line from one of my English professors: "Always assume that the writer [of the work under discussion] is at least as smart as you are."

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández I would look at the [2nd or 3rd definition for *rare*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rare) and also point to the phrase [*a rare bird*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rare+bird,+a) which refers to a "unique individual".

Comment: @Zairja Don’t forget the Bryant translation of the *Iliad*: *“Twelve mantles thence he took of texture rare; / Twelve single vests : twelve carpets next he chose: /  Tunics and finer robes, of each the same: / Of gold ten talents; polish’d tripods two; Four cauldrons, and a cup **of rare device** ;”*

Comment: Add Shakespeare, in *Cymbeline*, Act 1, Scene 6: *“Which I, the factor for the rest, have done /
In France: 'tis plate **of rare device,** and jewels /
Of rich and exquisite form; their values great;”*.  Just what you’d expect a guy who didn’t know how to spell his own name!

Comment: @tchrist if you keep going I'm going to start thinking Coleridge was using a well-worn phrase here!

Comment: @JAM Indeed: no *rara avis* was he.

Comment: Webster's Unabridged from 1913 defines *rare* as *Of an uncommon nature; unusually excellent; valuable to a degree seldom found*.

Comment: @JAM More Spencer, again from *Faerie Queen*, in Canto I Book 3 ll 3345–347: *“The love of Venus and her paramoure, / 
The fayre Adonis, turned to a flowre, /
A worke **of rare device** and wondrous wit.”*

Comment: @JAM Percy Bysshe Shelley, in *Revolt of Islam*, Canto I: *“And that strange boat like the moon's shade did sway / Amid reflected stars that in the waters lay:— /
A boat **of rare device,** which had no sail / But its own curved prow of thin moonstone, / Wrought like a web of texture fine and frail”.*  Definitely a well-worn phrase.

Comment: One thing I really like about this answer is that it illustrates (to me at least) how English evolved between the times of Spencer and Coolerige (about 150 years) from something that I have real trouble making any sense out of to something that is quite understandable, although a bit archaic looking in places.

Comment: @tchrist, just loving the survey of English lit. Very interesting, too, as T.E.D. points out.

Answer (score 3):

'Device' comes from the verb 'to devise' (create, invent). Device here relates to the act of devising, or the intangible idea of something having been created, not the thing itself. To our modern, machinery-focused mind, it seems that 'device' necessarily means a widget, but that is not so.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that whilst it is the pleasure dome that is being described, it is actually the miracle that is of rare device. The meaning being that it was not just any miracle but a rare and mystical one at that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case, *device* is being used much like we'd today use the word *artifice*. In other words, a complex manufactured or engineered object.

So basically what he meant by "rare device" is that this was a really impressive piece of complex engineering and craftmanship, not just your basic everyday building.